# Difference between in-memory-store and managed-store in mule cache

Tags: caching, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-cluster

What are the main differences between in-memory-store and managed-store in mule cache scope and which gives a best performance.

What is the best way to configure caching in global scope?

We are currently using in-memory-store caching. We are always getting issues with memory outage as we are using a server with less HW configurations. We are using mule 3.7v.

Please provide your suggestions to configure cache in optimized way.

We are facing issue with cache expiration with in-memory-store. cache date is not being expunged after expiration time also. But when we use "managed-store" its working as expected. 
Below is my configuration:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my friend clearly explained me this difference as follows:

> in-memory cache--> It is a temperoy memory storage area where it will store the data. for example:  Consider using a VM component in Mule, the data will be stored in VM in the form of in-memory queue
>
> in the case of Managed store--> we can store the data and use it in later stages. example: object store
>
> mainly cache will store the frequently used data. It will reduce the db or http calls by saving the frequently used data or results in cache scope.
>
> But both are for temporary storage only, means they are valid for that particular session alone.

Answer (score 3):

**In-memory:**
This store the data inside system memory. The data stored with In-memory is non-persistent which means in case of API restart or crash, the data been cached will be lost.

**Managed-store:**
This stores the data in a place defined by ListableObjectStore. The data stored with Managed-store is persistent which means in case of API restart or crash, the data been cached will no be lost.

Source (explained in detail with configuration difference):
http://www.tutorialsatoz.com/caching-in-mule-cache-scope/